# Access Denied when Menu CallBack Function is Called

Tags: forms, users, ajax

I am trying to call a function after the user clicks on an ajaxified link below.

```
$form['link'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',              
  '#markup' => l(t($record->studid),'myid_print/callback', array('attributes' => array('class' => 'use-ajax'))),                                
);
```

Below is my hook_menu function:

```
function myid_print_menu()
{  
    $items = array();   
    $items['myid_print/callback'] = array(    
        'page callback' => 'myid_print_user_page_callback', 
        'access callback'    => 'myid_print_user_access',
        'file' => 'myid_print.pages.inc',    
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,    
    );
    return $items;
}

function myid_print_user_access()
{      
    return TRUE;       
}
```

myid_print.pages.inc file:

```
function myid_print_user_page_callback()
{
    return 'Successful';
}
```

The above code throws the error below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Where am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried uninstalling my Jquery Update Module and suddenly the error disappears. I don't know why it works. Still thankful though.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX request is calling the path **/drupal-7.34/myid_print/callback** on the server. The path registered on your Drupal instance (assuming you're running under the drupal-7.34 directory) is **/drupal-7.34/print/callback**. Hence, the error you're seeing.

If you want to pass an argument to your print callback, you should do this.

```
$items['print/%/callback'] = array(    
    'page callback' => 'print_user_page_callback', 
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback'    => 'print_user_access',
    'file' => 'print.pages.inc',    
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,    
);

function print_user_page_callback($id)
{
    return 'Successful printing '.$id;
}
```

Read more on [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) if you'd like to understand more how module's can register paths.

Comment: Im sorry , but I just edited my code in the post to(print*) from (myid_print*). It was my mistake, sorry for not being consistent in my post but in my real code, it was really myid_print*